# How do I inject a dependency into a @FieldType plugin?

Tags: 8, plugins

I am implementing custom fields in Drupal 8 (types, widgets, formatters).

@FieldType plugins are instantiated by their respective plugin manager ([`\Drupal\Core\Field\FieldTypePluginManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Field!FieldTypePluginManager.php/class/FieldTypePluginManager/)) which does not care about dependency injection.  That is possible for both @FieldFormatter and @FieldWidget plugins if they only implement [`\Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Plugin!ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.php/interface/ContainerFactoryPluginInterface/).

What would be the alternative way to inject a dependency into a @FieldType plugin?

#### Notes

- @FieldType plugins are actually (implicitely) instantiated by [`\Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!TypedData!TypedDataManager.php/class/TypedDataManager/), which does not care about dependency injection
- Related drupal.org issue: [Allow typed data plugins to receive injected dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/node/2053415)

Comment: I don't think it's supported. e.g. `FieldItemBase::view()` uses `$view_builder = \Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder($this->getEntity()->getEntityTypeId())` even though the entity manager is injectable. I wouldn't have thought that's a mistake/oversight

Comment: Right. I was wondering if the injection should happen (calling the \Drupal::service methods) in an overidden createInstance method.

Comment: It wouldn't really be injection any more if the called class is instantiating its own service objects rather than being provided with them...not trying to nitpick or anything but IoC isn't IoC unless that control stays inverted :) The createInstance method sounds like as good a place as any but I might be wrong

Comment: Thanks for not nitpicking :). I do agree however regarding IoC, hence came my question in the first place :-) Not having DI options for @FieldType seems odd, especially when writing unit tests.

Answer (score 9):

An example for a field formatter plugin with dependency injections. This works differently from services. First parameter injected is the container to get all services needed.

**Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter**

```
class StringFormatter extends FormatterBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * Constructs a StringFormatter instance.
   *
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the formatter.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition
   *   The definition of the field to which the formatter is associated.
   * @param array $settings
   *   The formatter settings.
   * @param string $label
   *   The formatter label display setting.
   * @param string $view_mode
   *   The view mode.
   * @param array $third_party_settings
   *   Any third party settings settings.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity type manager.
   */
  public function __construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, array $settings, $label, $view_mode, array $third_party_settings, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {
    parent::__construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $field_definition, $settings, $label, $view_mode, $third_party_settings);
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $configuration['field_definition'],
      $configuration['settings'],
      $configuration['label'],
      $configuration['view_mode'],
      $configuration['third_party_settings'],
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @4k4, that is a good example. OP is about FieldTypes not FieldFormatters though.

Comment: ... implementing custom fields in Drupal 8 (types, widgets, formatters). But it's the same for all plugins.

Comment: Ah, so all plugins can implement  `ContainerFactoryPluginInterface` and that makes Drupal instantiate them differently @4k4? That makes sense as you need to do the same for blocks

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: But the FieldTypePluginManager will not check if the plugin implements that interface and will also not pass along the container. This is what FieldWidget/FieldFormatter PluginManager do, I assume BlockPluginManager as well.

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis. You're right, FieldTypePluginManager doesn't support the ContainerFactory. Did assume that all plugins support this.

Comment: @4k4: Thanks :-) Needed someone to check that too, it seems that FieldType plugins are quite different in that aspect.

Comment: I was talking to @Berdir about this the other day in IRC, but forget what he said.  Hopefully he will see this and chime in.

Comment: I did some research in the code. The container factory is in DefaultPluginManager. So all plugin manager should be able to provide the container. But I don't know why the formatter and widget and two or three other plugin managers have extra code for this.

Comment: Because FieldType plugins are essentially typed data plugins and are instantiated through that and typed data currently doesn't support this, it would need its own interface as it has special constructor arguments. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2053415

Comment: Thanks for the link, that issue is where work needs to be done it seems.

Comment: @Berdir Seeing that the patch in https://www.drupal.org/node/2053415 is not yet in Drupal Core, it is possible to inject services into the Field Types plugins or not? If it is possible where I can find an example?

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: I updated the answer to use the EntityTypeManager. @4k4 – Could you please review my edits? Is it OK that way?

Comment: Yes, since my answer the core example changed in the same way, see https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/commit/62e59a00f2c0c4f1577b307eb9f80b703060e981

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works for the field widget and field formatter classes. The actual @fieldType definition class constructor requires this signature:

```
public function __construct(
   \Drupal\Core\TypedData\ComplexDataDefinitionInterface $definition, 
   $name = NULL, 
   \Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataInterface $parent = NULL
)
```

This works for Drupal 8, 9 and 10. For an example, refer to the [FieldItemBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemBase.php/class/FieldItemBase/10) class.