# Dependency injection in FieldItemList

Tags: 9, dependency-injection

I'm creating a few custom classes that extend FieldItemList and they need some services injected.

I've had a look at core classes that extend that class and none of them do dependency injection, they all call \Drupal::service().

Is there a way to inject services here or should I follow the core pattern?

Comment: No, there is still no way to inject services and you have to use the static service wrapper. See this comment and the linked issue https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224247/how-do-i-inject-a-dependency-into-a-fieldtype-plugin/224248#comment273484_224248

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I inject a dependency into a @FieldType plugin?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224247/how-do-i-inject-a-dependency-into-a-fieldtype-plugin)

Comment: FieldItemList isn't a field type plugin strictly speaking, but it sounds like the same thing applies. I'm going to wrap the services I need in my own service so I only have to call the service wrapper once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field type plugin manager instantiates both, FieldItem and FieldItemList via the typed data manager:

*Drupal\Core\Field\FieldTypePluginManager*

```
  public function createFieldItemList(FieldableEntityInterface $entity, $field_name, $values = NULL) {
    // Leverage prototyping of the Typed Data API for fast instantiation.
    return $this->typedDataManager->getPropertyInstance($entity->getTypedData(), $field_name, $values);
  }

  public function createFieldItem(FieldItemListInterface $items, $index, $values = NULL) {
    // Leverage prototyping of the Typed Data API for fast instantiation.
    return $this->typedDataManager->getPropertyInstance($items, $index, $values);
  }
```

To be able to inject services you need to wait until this issue [Allow typed data plugins to receive injected dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/node/2053415) is resolved.